# Let {Xt}t≥0 a compound Poisson process with λ=2 where Yi∼Exp(1). We define τ=inf{t≥0:Xt≥10}. Find the PDF of τ.

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Hello I have been aked this and I don't know how to proceed:
Let {Xt}t≥0 a compound Poisson process with λ=2 where Yi∼Exp(1). We define τ=inf{t≥0:Xt≥10}. Find the PDF of τ.
I would be great if you have any hint for this, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1. What is a compound Poisson process with $\lambda=\color{red}{2}$ and $Y_i\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\color{red}{1})$ ? 2. Show your own attempts .

Comment: Here $X(t)=\sum_{i
\leq N(t)}Y_i$ where $N(t)\sim \text{Poisson}(2t)$ and $Y_1,Y_2,...\sim \exp(1)$. Notice $\tau>t$ if and only if $X(t)<10$. Can you continue?